# Hibernate select relevent data in one query

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate, select, hql

I am new to Hibernate.
This is a `User` table

```
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id    | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| name  | varchar(16) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| age   | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| sex   | char(1)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

This is my sample data

```
+----+-------+------+------+
| id | name  | age  | sex  |
+----+-------+------+------+
|  1 | Amit  |   20 | M    |
|  2 | Sumit |   21 | M    |
|  3 | Mohan |   22 | M    |
|  4 | Ram   |   26 | M    |
|  5 | John  |   22 | M    |
|  6 | Sita  |   19 | F    |
+----+-------+------+------+
```

These are my queries:

```
select id from User where name="Amit" and age=20;
select id from User where name="Ram" and age=26;
select id from User where name="Mohan" and age=22;
select id from User where name="Sita" and age=19;
```

I can do this in hibernate by running 4 queries.
Is there any way by which I can do this in just one query?
Please tell the same can be done in mysql too.
Please help. Any clue, link or reference will be appreciable.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this

```
select  id , name ,age , sex from User 
where (name,age) IN (('Amit','20'),('Ram', '26'),('Mohan', '22'),('Sita', '19'));
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7b8e76/2)

Answer (score 1):

In sql ...

```
select name, id from User where ( name="Amit" and age=20)
                             or ( name="Ram" and age=26 )
                             or ( name="Mohan" and age=22 )
                             or ( name="Sita" and age=19 )
```

Comment: Thank you Dave. This is helpful too.